# Git server access on windows using windows auth and logged in user

Tags: git, version-control, sspi

I have successfully installed Smart-HTTP Git server on IIS (gitweb.codeplex.com) and configured access using Windows authentication, but each access to server repository from client requires username/password entry.

Is it possible to configure access using current logged in user credentials - something like :sspi: in cvsnt? (can switch to another server if necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wanders on that question - here is solution for client side to configure ssh with auth via kerberos (server was configured by our admin).

1. Install "Putty with Kerberos"
2. Install git and choose user plink as ssh and choose plink from "Putty with Kerberos".
3. If environment variable GIT_SSH is not set to plink, set it manually
4. Run putty from putty.exe "Putty with Kerberos". Enter path to your server and choose ssh.
   In Connection/SSH/Kerberos select "Attempt Kerberos auth (SSH-2)" on the same page in "auto-login username" select "User name portion of user principal name"
   In Connection/SSH/Auth unselect "Bypass authentication entirely (SSH-2 only)" and unselect "Display pre-authentication banner (SSH-2 only)."
   Go back in session and save settings in "Default Settings"
5. Connect to your server and then it offers to save public key of server in registry - agree.